# Can I set duration to fluttertoast?

Tags: flutter, toast, flutter-web

I am intending to use this library https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast/install for toasts.

Is there a way to set the duration. This is a web project, in case it makes any difference.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I've found:

The duration for which a toast is displayed on screen is unfortunately defined by a flag: **you can either show it for a SHORT duration, which is 2 seconds or a LONG duration which is 3,5 seconds**.
[source](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/988256/how-to-show-a-toast-for-a-specific-duration-in-and#:%7E:text=The%20duration%20for%20which%20a,which%20is%203%2C5%20seconds.)

The package `fluttertoast` only implements those two types of duration and if you want a longer toast you will need to make your own implementation using native code.